# Shadow MQTT - reg

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

I am using aws-iot-ask-python to communicate with the AWS IOT on the cloud. I have created a shadow to the "thing". I want to perform "update" operation.

I am publishing to the `$aws/things/thingName/shadow/update` from the AWS IOT test. On the device side I want to subscribe to `$aws/things/thingName/shadow/update/accepted` and `$aws/things/thingName/shadow/update/rejected`.

The problem is the function provided by the SDK is `shadowUpdate(jsonPacket, CallbackFunction, timeout)` but this function performs both the publish and subscribe operations at the same time. According to my requirement I don't want to perform publish from device. Can u guys suggest me a solution to this problem.

Comment: Which library are you using? I can see [aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2: Next generation AWS IoT Client SDK for Python using the AWS Common Runtime](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2) and there is also the normal [boto3 Python library](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iot-data.html#IoTDataPlane.Client.update_thing_shadow). Any chance you can add more details to your question, such as showing relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

The device can subscribe for shadow updates by using `shadowRegisterDeltaCallback()`. Alternatively it can get the current state using `shadowGet()`.

See https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-docs/html/index.html#AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.shadow.deviceShadow.deviceShadow.shadowRegisterDeltaCallback and https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-docs/html/index.html#AWSIoTPythonSDK.core.shadow.deviceShadow.deviceShadow.shadowGet

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. The problem is my device shouldn't update. We are updating from MQTT Test app on the cloud side. So the device is unaware of the update